# WPF Styling ContentControl in Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contentcontrol

I have this style for `ContentControl`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="textbox">
        <TextBox Text="edit me"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="textblock">
        <TextBlock Text="can't edit"/>
    </DataTemplate>

 <Style x:Key="ContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource textblock}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                             AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem},AncestorLevel=1}}" 
                                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource textbox}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And that codes:

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView  x:Name="UGridview1">
                <GridViewColumn Width=" 90">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl >
                                
                            </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

But I want to create the columns dynamically, so I wrote the following codes:

```
for (x = 0; x <= Lvobj.obj.Length - 1; x++) // ClmnCount - 1
    {
       
        GridViewColumn_ = new GridViewColumn();
        GridViewColumn_.SetValue(NameProperty, "Column" + x);
        GridViewColumn_.Header = Lvobj.obj(x)(clmntxt);
        GridViewColumn_.Width = 99;


        /// This part doesnt work
        ContentControl cntr = new ContentControl();
        cntr.Style = this.Resources("ContentControlStyle");
        ///
       
        GridViewColumn_.CellTemplate = cntr.ContentTemplate;
        UGridview1.Columns.Add(GridViewColumn_);
    }
```

It never works. What must i do for i can create columns with `ContentControl` Style?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is `this.Resources("ContentControlStyle")`? It must be with square brackets, it's a dictionary: `this.Resources["ContentControlStyle"]`. When are you looking up the style resource?

Comment: Make sure to not lookup the style before UserControl.OnInitialized  is called. You can override `OnInitialized` in your UserControl and then initialize the ListView or handle the Loaded event.

Comment: Or consider to define the style implicit (without a `x:key`). Then the style will be applied automatically once the target is loaded.

Comment: I changed it that way. The problem was "VisualTree", it was not seeing the ContentControl element. Because it was not FrameworkElementFactory element.

Comment: It's not about FrameworkElementFactory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `XamlReader.Parse` API with a `DynamicResource`:

```
const string Xaml = @"<DataTemplate " +
    @"xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""> " +
    @"<ContentControl Style=""{DynamicResource ContentControlStyle}"" />" +
    "</DataTemplate>";
DataTemplate DataTemplate_ = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(Xaml) as DataTemplate;
GridViewColumn_.CellTemplate = DataTemplate_;
```

Or create a `FrameworkElementFactory`:

```
FrameworkElementFactory cc = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
cc.SetValue(ContentControl.StyleProperty, this.Resources["ContentControlStyle"]);
GridViewColumn_.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = cc };
```

Comment: "FrameworkElementFactory cc = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));" code made the program run. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Access the `ResourceDictionary` with square brackets (it's a `Dictionary`):

```
this.Resources["ContentControlStyle"]
```

Make sure to not lookup the style before `UserControl.OnInitialized`  is called. You can override `OnInitialized` in your `UserControl` and then initialize the `ListView`. Alternatively handle the `Loaded` event.

Alternatively (recommended), consider to define the style implicit (without a `x:key`). Then the style will be applied automatically, once the target is loaded. This way you don't have to deal with the resources.
You can limit the scope by defining it inside the `ResourceDictionary` of the `ListView`:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Setter Property="Content"
              Value="{Binding}" />
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource textblock}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                         AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem},AncestorLevel=1}}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                  Value="{StaticResource textbox}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListView.Resources>

  <ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="UGridview1">
      <GridViewColumn Width=" 90">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```